# How call to variadic method from Objective-C macro?

Tags: objective-c, macros, variadic-functions

I created a va_list version of variadic method:

```
+(void)myFunc:(NSString *)message args:(va_list)args;
```

and created macro `TESTLOG` that call to above function

```
#define TESTLOG(x,...) [MyExample myFunc:(x), ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

the problem is that when i am try calling to `TESTLOG` macro, I get an error:

```
TESTLOG("test");
TESTLOG(@"test",@"test1");
```

> Expected expression

How I can solve this issue? I tried to replace `args:(va_list)args` with `...` it is working, but in my case I need to use the va_list and macro.

I think that my issue is with the definition in the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `__VA_ARGS__` macro with a `va_list` argument. Your Objective-C method needs to be defined as:

```
+ (void)myFunc:(NSString *)message, ... ;
```

Then your macro can be:

```
#define TESTLOG(x,...) [MyExample myFunc:(x), __VA_ARGS__]
```

Comment: Rmaddy you are correct, but in my case the situation is more complicated...
In this case I can run this function from objective-c code and it is ok, but what about swift?

How I can call this function( MyExample.myFunc ) from a swift code? with the variadic method?

I didn't succeed to call a variadic method from swift code, xcode didn't recognize the function (MyExample.myFunc).

Can you please  explain me how to declare the swift function that call to myFunc?

Comment: That's a completely separate question. You should close this one by accepting the answer and then post a new question asking how to call an Objective-C variadic method from Swift.